# ValueError when performing integration in Numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy, numerical-integration

I am receiving a `ValueError` which I cannot decifer. I am tryig to perform a simple integration task, using the `integrate.quad` on a `lambda` function. Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
p = np.arange(0,1,1/1000)
x = 0
y = 1
z = 0.9
pdfl = lambda p: 2*(p-x)/((y-x)*(z-x)) if p<z else 2*(y-p)/((y-x)*(y-z))
h = lambda pp: integrate.quad(lambda p: p*pdfl(p), 0, pp)
```

In this code, `pdfl` is the probability density function of a (skewed) triangular distribution. Now, this function works for particular numbers, that is, `h(0.5)` gives us an answer as desired. However, I would like to have `h` evaluated at each of the elements in `p`. But when I do `h(p)`, I get the exception:

```
  File "d:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\quadpack.py", line 315, in quad
    points)

  File "d:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\quadpack.py", line 364, in _quad
    if (b != Inf and a != -Inf):

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Any advice on how to overcome this error? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error, as you can see from the side bar questions, is the result of using an array in a context that expects a scalar True/False.

My guess is the `quad` is testing the bounds, `pp` against `inf`.  It works fine when you give it one bounds, e.g. `0.5`, but produces this error when you give it an array of bounds, `p`.  `quad` is designed to work with one set of bounds at a time, not an array.

I think you need to do something like

```
res = [h(pp) for pp in p]
```

that is, iterate, performing the integration for one bound value at a time.